# How to get journalctl logs from container in docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker compose file and 3 containers up with this file. in one of 
 the container,the application(sampleappservice) sends log to journalctl and I want to catch it.How can I get it?
Here is my compose file:
**

```
version: '3'
services:                
    simulatorservice:
        image: "data-simulator:latest"
        container_name: data-simulator
        build: 
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-simulator
        ports : 
        - "55501:55501"
        volumes:
        - ./data:/opt/apps/DataSimulator/data
    mosquittoservice:
        image: "databus:latest"
        container_name: databus
        build: 
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-databus        
        ports : 
        - "1883:1883"
    sampleappservice:##I need to get this container journalctl log.
        image: "sampleapp:latest"
        container_name: sampleapp
        build: 
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-sampleapp
```

**

Comment: I just don't understand what you're asking and it looks like you didn't spend one second re-reading what you wrote. You've got to spend a bare minimum of time writing a clear question if you want people to spend time answering it.

Comment: @Alkaline sorry,is it clear now?

Comment: `docker logs sampleappservice`

Comment: Where do you want to catch it? From inside one of the other containers? Otherwise @Sathya is correct.

Comment: from outside. Thanx Sathya.But it could be bettter to get journalctl logs from outside..

Comment: I'm not sure that you're aware but the standard tool to inspect journald logs is journalctl. Eg: `sudo journalctl -u docker`. However it will show you the logs for all the containers.